# BlackBerry accessing JavaScript variable in BrowserField

Tags: javascript, blackberry, browserfield

I'm using 5.0 `BrowserField` and I'm able to invoke JavaScript function using

```
browser.executeScript("..");
```

I need to read JavaScript variable. It's possible
 to directly access JS variable, or should I ask 3rd party to provide JS function for that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
Object val= null;
                   try {
                       val = browser.executeScript("variable_name");
                   } catch (Exception ex) {
                       // ...
                   }
```